# How to keep Android App updated for test users?

Tags: android

I have a question concerning Android app development. I'm about to develop an app that I want to give to test users. Testing the app on my own phone means plugging it in my laptop and updating it manually. Do you know any solution that provides automatic updating for in-progress-apps without plugging each phone in on each update? 
Maybe there is a google play store function I don't know about yet that lets you "hide" you app before publication and you can share the link with designated people?

Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 5):

The Play Store offers [alpha and beta testing](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en), which allows you to upload and distribute test builds via the Play Store.

If you use this feature, you control which version of your application testers will receive on their devices, and they will automatically get updates.

You do not need your application to be publicly available to use this feature.